# Split Pandas column by delimiter and legth (on whole sentences)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with long descriptions listed in a column (sometimes exceeding 3000 symbols).
e.g.

```
     doc    name         text           len
0   doc_1   Texas   I have a dream....  3110
1   doc_1   Texas   This dream is a.... 3111
2   doc_2   Georgia I love eating....   3325
3   doc_2   Georgia Chick fil A is....  3325
4   doc_2   Georgia Worl of coke....    3325
5   doc_2   Georgia Atlanta Falcons.... 3325
6   doc_2   Idaho   Yesterday was....   2500
7   doc_2   Idaho   The potatoes....    2500
:     :       :          :               :
:     :       :          :               :
n   doc_n    NY     Big Apple is....    2407
```

In order to make it easy for import I need to split the 'text' column in up to 300 symbols columns e.g. 'text1', 'text2'... where each chunk should end at a whole sentence.
I've looked at many solutions but they are either for delimiter or length, not both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`nltk`](https://www.nltk.org/) to split your text into sentences, then a custom function to combine the chunks in strings up to the maximum length:

```
import nltk

def split_sentences(text, max_len=300, prefix='col'):
    out = []
    tmp = []
    L = 0
    for sentence in nltk.sent_tokenize(text):
        L += len(sentence)+1
        if L > max_len:
            out.append(' '.join(tmp))
            tmp = []
            L = len(sentence)
        tmp.append(sentence)
    out.append(' '.join(tmp))
    return pd.Series(out).rename(lambda x: f'{prefix}_{x+1}')

out = df.join(df['text'].apply(split_sentences)).drop(columns='text')
```

Example output (using a [Lorem Ipsum](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum) as input text):

```
   other                                              col_1                                              col_2                                              col_3  \
0      1  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipis...  Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, en...  Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit...   
1      2  LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUR ADIPIS...  PROIN PORTTITOR, ORCI NEC NONUMMY MOLESTIE, EN...  PRAESENT EGESTAS LEO IN PEDE. PRAESENT BLANDIT...   

                                               col_4  
0  Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hend...  
1  MAECENAS ADIPISCING ANTE NON DIAM SODALES HEND...
```

Reproducible input:

```
lipsum = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue. Praesent egestas leo in pede. Praesent blandit odio eu enim. Pellentesque sed dui ut augue blandit sodales. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aliquam nibh. Mauris ac mauris sed pede pellentesque fermentum. Maecenas adipiscing ante non diam sodales hendrerit.'''
df = pd.DataFrame({'other': [1, 2], 'text': [lipsum, lipsum.upper()]})
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Did the job perfectly.